# Custom loop by url

Tags: categories, loop

So currently I have this working for 'search' ie: if I do www.domain.com/search/query, it returns everything it finds on the word 'query'. I would like to utilize that loop/template I created within that search.php but change it to posts. Then query a specific post category if possible ie: www.domain.com/posts/category1

I'm think it all stems off changing

```
<?php get_template_part('loop', 'search'); ?>
```

Fairly new to wordpress so any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you "have this working for 'search'"? Are you using a plugin? You should include the contents of `loop-search.php` in your question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customise the loop query to get results based on a search term - with $s being the search term;

```
<?php // Post Query
$args=array(
's'      => $s, 
);
?>
<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```